# Show only one day of the week in Date column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I've created a Date column and used the calendar function to list a date range. Here's the DAX formula I used:

```
Data = Calendar( Date(2018, 4, 1), Date(2021,4,30))
```

However, what I'm trying to achieve now that I have the date range specified is I only want Tuesdays to be shown and no other day of the week. How do I achieve this exactly?

Apologies if this is a silly question, I'm completely new to this.

I tried using the Date filters option but that didn't help unfortunately. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a FILTER function:

```
Data = FILTER(
    Calendar( Date(2018, 4, 1), Date(2021,4,30)),
    WEEKDAY([Date]) =3)
```

[image: FILTER]

Bonus  for confirmation:

If we want to confirm:

[image: DERD]

Comment: Thank you! this is the most straightforward answer that I've been looking for.

Comment: You're welcome! Nice to hear!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can accept this answer:

```
Data = 
VAR tbl =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR( DATE(2018, 4, 1), DATE(2021, 4, 30)),
        "Weekday", WEEKDAY([Date], 2)
    )
RETURN
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        FILTER( tbl, [Weekday] = 2),
        "Date", [Date]
    )
```

[image]